# « touches quoi ? » - la signification possible

Tags: expressions, expressions-idiomatiques, registre-familier

J'ai assisté récemment à une dispute entre un jeune homme et une jeune femme, où le dialogue se développait comme ça :

> L'homme : mais **tu touches quoi ?**
> La femme : ça ne te regarde pas.

Il a répété sa question plusieurs fois, alors que la femme était évasive - ses réponses variaient. (Il a essayé de lui barrer la route avec le vélo, alors qu'elle, manifestement, voulait partir. Je ne suis pas intervenu, car l'homme ne semblait pas violent, même si très agité. En outre, nous étions dans le centre ville, avec beaucoup de monde autour de nous.)

Je me pose la question sur la signification de la question **« tu touches quoi ? »** Car j'ignore le contexte du débat, je ne sais pas, si la femme avait littéralement **touché** quelque chose ou s'il s'agit d'une forme plus familière de question sur un salaire : **« tu touches combien ? »**

Q : Néanmoins, voyant l'agitation de jeune homme, je me demande, s'il peut être d'une autre sens - peut-être plus offensif et/ou spécifique.

Comment: Dans le sens "quelles prestations sociales te sont verséés ?" (*ce qui n'est qu'une hypothèse totalement  invérifiable*), la formulation de la question serait tout à fait correcte et appropriée.

Comment: En argot, _tu touches_ peut aussi vouloir dire _être doué à faire quelque chose_, mais peut-être pas applicable dans le cas ici.

Comment: @RogerVadim ça pourrait être beaucoup de choses... on ne saura probablement jamais sans plus de contexte. Se connaissaient-ils ? Quel lien entre eux ? Pourquoi une altercation à cet endroit-là ? etc. etc.

Comment: **Gardons les commentaires sur le sujet s'il vous plaît.** [Vous pouvez regarder ici](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) pour une explication de la façon dont les commentaires sont censés être utilisés et comment ils ne sont pas censés être utilisés. Merci!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Ici, il s'agit probablement d'argent.

"Toucher" est souvent utilisé dans le sens de "recevoir", pour parler d'une quantité d'argent. On peut dire par exemple qu'on touche une prime, ou des allocations...

Je vois deux sens possibles à cette question:

- "Quelle est la nature de tes recettes d'argent?": l'homme demande à la femme si elle est par exemple bénéficiaire d'aides sociales, et lesquelles. Ce serait la formulation la plus grammaticalement correcte.
- "Tu touches quelle quantité?": l'homme demande à la femme combien elle reçoit d'argent. Ce n'est pas tout à fait correct (on dirait plutôt "tu touches combien?"), mais c'est tout de même possible dans un contexte où le premier souci des interlocuteurs n'est pas l'exactitude grammaticale.

Les autres sens du mot "toucher" ne conviennent pas au contexte.